# How to stream Http response with custom response formatter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, content-negotiation, responsestream

I have a REST controller that streams the response in csv format using a helper method like below:

```
public static void CsvStreamHelper(IEnumerable<T> data, Stream stream)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        foreach (var line in data)
        {
            // format csv lines here
            writer.WriteLine(lineString);
        }

        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Then, I'm using this in my Controller like:

```
public Task<IActionResult> MyController()
{
    var data = // Get data here.

    CsvStreamHelper(data, this.HttpContext.Response.Body);

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

This is working fine. However, I would like to use content negotiation middleware with custom formatter [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) while continue to stream response.

I can override `WriteResponseBodyAsync` method using my helper method. What I'm unsure about is if I use it in my Rest controller like `this.Ok(data)`, instead of streaming the response, it will just build the response and send it in one chunk. How can I achieve streaming response with content negotiation middleware?

Comment: Have you tried options like System.Net.Http.StreamContent and System.Net.Http.PushStreamContent? http://blog.guvweb.co.uk/2014/07/02/streaming-web-api/

Comment: Both these APIs seem to be old... I've used PushStreamContent in .Net Framework. I don't think it's the way to go with .Net Core.